# Solving trig equation where $\sin (\theta + 60°) = \sin 2 \theta$

Tags: trigonometry

I solved the equation $\sec θ + \sqrt{3} \cscθ = 4$

The question required us to use $\sinθ + \sqrt{3} \cosθ = 2 \sin 2θ$. After doing all of this I ended up with

$\sin(θ+60)=\sin(2θ)$

The range is $0< θ < 180$ and the solutions $60, 40 \text { and } 160$

I understand why its $60$ but not the rest.

Does anyone mind explaining the reasoning for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this $$\sec(x)+\sqrt[3]{\csc(x)}=4$$?

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner no it is root3 * cosec (x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $sin(180^o - \theta) = sin(\theta) and sin(180^o + \theta) = - sin(\theta)= sin(-\theta)$

So case-1, using $sin(\theta + 60) = sin(2\theta), \theta + 60 = 2\theta$

or$ \theta = 60$

case-2,using $sin(\theta + 60) = sin(180 - \theta - 60) = sin(2\theta)$
$$ sin(120 - \theta) = sin(2\theta)$$
$$ 120 - \theta = 2\theta$$
$$ 120 = 3\theta$$
$$ \theta = 40$$

Aliter

$sin(60+\theta) = sin(2\theta)$ $$ sin(60+\theta) - sin(2\theta) = 0$$
Applying$ sin A - sin B = 2 cos \frac{A+B}{2} sin\frac{A-B}{2}$
$$2cos\frac{60+\theta+2\theta}{2}sin\frac{60+\theta - 2\theta}{2} = 0$$
$$cos(30 + \frac{3\theta}{2})sin(30 - \frac{\theta}{2})= 0$$

Now either$$ cos(30 + \frac{3\theta}{2}) = 0$$ or$$sin(30 - \frac{\theta}{2})= 0$$
$ cos(30 + \frac{3\theta}{2}) = 0 = cos 90$ or $cos 270$

Taking 90, $30 + \frac{3\theta}{2} = 90, \frac{3\theta}{2} = 60, \theta = 40$

Taking 270, $30 + \frac{3\theta}{2} = 270, \frac{3\theta}{2} = 240, \theta = 160$

Similarly take sin 0 = sin 180 = 0, to get 60(case 1).

Thank you.

Comment: I wa wondering why in case 1 we leave it as it is and dont use the two concepts you mention above.

Comment: The reason is for sin(a) = sin( b), we have the general solution of a = n*pi + (-1)^n*b

Comment: And using n = 0, we have a = 0 + 1.b (case-1)

Comment: can you show  me the third case because Im not getting it for some reason

Comment: I have found another way which I answer below, by which you can find all the 3 cases by a single equation(pls. wait for 2 mins.)

Comment: Oh okay, thank you!